# Tabular - applying newcommand with option to a full column

Tags: tables, formatting, columns

I have a created a command with an option, such as (just an example):

```
\newcommand{\form}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\textit{#1}}}
```

I want to apply this format to a full column in a tabular environment. With a simple color format I would usually do as follow :

```
\begin{tabular}{|>{\color{red}}c|c|}
```

How can I do something similar with my "form" command. I tried the following codes without any results:

```
\begin{tabular}{|>{\form{}}c|c|}   %compiles with no changes
\begin{tabular}{|>{\form}c|c|}     %compiles with no changes
\begin{tabular}{|>{\form{#1}}c|c|} %does not compile
```

Thanks

Comment: Would it help if you define a new column type like `\usepackage{array} \newcolumntype{C}{>{\color{red}\itshape}c}` and use `C` instead of `c` in your table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case, `>{\color{red}\itshape}c` is sufficient, but for more general situations you can use `collcell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand{\form}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textit{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  >{\collectcell\form}c<{\endcollectcell} % red italic
  >{\color{red}\itshape}c % red italic as well
}
abc & defghi \\
defghi & abc
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico , thanks to both of you, it works perfectly using the collectcell call. My actual form command is much more complex, that's why i need a command with an argument.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `\begin{tabular}{|>{\form{#1}}c|c|}` can't work because LaTeX is expecting not a formal argument ("`#1`") but a specific argument, say, "blurb". For instance, `\begin{tabular}{|>{\form{blurb}}c|c|}` works fine.

A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,xcolor}
\newcommand{\form}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\textit{#1}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\form{blurb}}c|c|}
aaa & bbb \\
ccc & ddd
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Every cell in the first column of the table will receive the prefix "blurb", in blue and italics.

---

If, however, the objective is to make all cells in the first column blue and italic, it suffices to define `\form` as follows:

```
\newcommand{\form}{\color{blue}\itshape}
```

and to start the `tabular` environment as follows: `\begin{tabular}{|>{\form}c|c|}`.